# How to limit the amount of tags allowed in django-taggit?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am using the django-taggit module for tagging posts on my website, however I want to limit the amount of tags allowed to only 3. I have read the documentation, and have been able to find nothing.

Here is my model for Posts

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='posts',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=75)
    text = models.TextField()

   #... other fields here

    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And now here is the views

```py
class PostListView(SelectRelatedMixin,TagMixin,ListView):
    model = Post    
    hit_count = True
    template_name = 'mainapp/post_list.html'
    selected_related = ("user","group")
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = models.Post.objects.all()

    def get(self,request,):
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-published_date')
        users = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
        count= User.objects.all().count()
        friend, created = Friend.objects.get_or_create(current_user=request.user)
        friends = friend.users.all()
        group = Group.objects.all()
        args = {
            'users':users, 'friends':friends, 'posts':posts, 'group':group,'count':count
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, args)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('-published_date')
```

Here is the form

```py
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = Post
        fields = ['title','text','group','image','file','tags','spoiler','NSFW']
        widgets = {
            'title':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'textinputclass'}),
            'text':forms.Textarea(attrs={'class':'textareaclass editable'}),

        }
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['image'].required = False
        self.fields['file'].required = False
```

So I want to know how I can limit the amount of tags the user can enter for the post

Comment: Can you provide a link to `django-taggit`?

Comment: Sure.
https://github.com/jazzband/django-taggit

https://django-taggit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: "...I want to limit the amount of tags allowed to only 3." Does this mean that each post can only have three tags max?

Comment: ye, that's what i mean. so like, the post has a max of 3, and anything after that isnt valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    ...

    def clean_tags(self):
        tn = self.cleaned_data.get('tags', [])
        if len(tn) > 3:
            raise ValidationError('Invalid number of tags', code='invalid')

   ...
```

More Info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: Thanks for that, it works, however I get this error whenever I try to submit the post again with the right amount of tags
`set() argument after * must be an iterable, not NoneType`
So I will put 4 tags in, it'll give me the error saying too many tags, and then I will change it so there are 3 or less tags, and I get that error

Comment: Hello Jeremy,  for debugging purposes, you can always check `self.instance.tags.all()`.